# Modify package.xml

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I just have a question when writing the ROS wiki page for my package. If I modify package.xml file (such as add author, change maintainer, ...), the ROS wiki page will automatically update or I need to do something else?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225876/modify-package.xml/) by [tn0432](https://answers.ros.org/users/21276/tn0432/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2016-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK, when you release your package, after pull request and merge progress, if you have `doc:` information in `distribution.yaml`, jenkins will update the wiki header periodically.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2